# Exact Pharse Match in Solr with single/multi words for text field

Tags: java, search, solr, full-text-search

I have a big problem and questions regarding solr behaviour,could you please help me to solve this.

Don't mind my questions are too long.

My client have a requirement like the following below.

- We need a matchall and matchallpartial scenarios.
- It depends on search field we do matchall or matchallpartial in our application level.

and we have wildcard as well left,right,both are the wildcard entries.

I used Keyword tokenizer for indexing as well as querying it is satisfying my requirement in all scenarios.But synonyms,stopwords and stemming not working at all.Because i used keyword tokenizer and it is building queries like whole phrase.I tried with StandaradTokenizer factory it is failing only matchall scenario remaining it is working fine.

Could you please post some example queries and suggestions to get exact matches with single word/multiword .

e.g.
If my field has 
"Indicators Indicator Components" this is whole phrase.i am getting results even though i am searching for "indicator" i don't want that.

If i use keyword tokenizer i am getting what i want but it is failing in synonyms,stopwords scenarios.

Some times(depends on the logic) i will use same text filed for matchallpartial scenario that time i want results for "indicator" how can i get exact matchall for whole phrase/word by using stadardtokenizer.

Please help me.

Thanks,
Sri

Comment: don't forget you can index multiple times the same field with different tokenizers; you could have a tokenized version that you query for partial matches, and a more exact version that you query for complete matches.

Comment: Yann how can I use different tokenizers for different fields..

Comment: Yes, you can define various fieldTypes in your schema; typically for an exact match you would use KeywordTokenizerFactory (which doesn't actually tokenize), and for partial matches, a StandardTokenizerFactory. You can index the same content in both fields (one field with each type), and depending on the type of match you want, query or the other field.

Answer (score 1):

I am listing two examples which will surely help to get exact match

My first query is :- `/select?q=name:anand kishore` - By this way I will get 1000 records which will be having name anand or kishore or both

My Second query is :- `/select?q=name:"anand kishore"` - By this I will get 60 results of the records which will have anand kishore like, (anand kishore tripathy, kamal anand kishore)

My Third query is :- `/select?q=name:"kamal anand kishore"` - By this I will get only one result which is matching exactly, i.e kamal anand kishore

Comment: select?q=(sectionName_text_en_gb:("Indicators Components"^10.0)) i am not getting any results. i am using now StadardKeyywordTokenizer

Comment: Working for me this is what i am using in fields
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
   <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
   <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
   <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" 
    expand="false"/> -->
   <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
   continue....

Comment: <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
   <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
   <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" />
   <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
  </analyzer>
 </fieldType>